# @ngtools/webpack not bundling with angular6 but working fine with angular5

Tags: webpack, angular6, angular-aot

My angular application was earlier on Angular5 , which was working well with webpack and @ngtools/webpack to get AOT build. But after migrating to Angular6 that build is not happening i,e there is no build file in dist directory. Also there is no error while webpack building.

Comment: you can go through this link 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10384